# Reading a Word doc from Sharepoint and displaying in Word

Tags: office-addins

In a Word/Office Add-In, given a link to a Word doc in Sharepoint, could the Add-In tell the current instance of Word to open the doc?  Alternatively, is it possible to read that Word doc from Sharepoint, and have that doc populate the Word editing window?  If so, any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the silence was deafening.  However, I wound up building a small REST API so the addin calls the REST API which fetches the document, serializes it to BASE 64, and returns it to the AddIn.  The AddIn is then able to insert it into the doc.